# Cannot assign a value of type String! to a value of type String

Tags: ios, swift

Here's code:

```
section.name = (alert.textFields[0] as! UITextField).text
```

I have an error `Cannot assign a value of type String! to a value of type String`

`section` is a Core Data `NSManagedObject` subclass with required value of name.

Comment: Did you try unwrapping .text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
section.name = (alert.textFields![0] as UITextField).text
```

For `Swift 1.2`

```
section.name = (alert.textFields![0] as! UITextField).text
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check `alert.textFields` isn't `nil` before you can use the subscript. Which you're not doing in your code sample.

In my opinion, the best way to get the value of `text` is to use optional binding, like so:

```
if let textField = alert.textFields?[0] as? UITextField {
    section.name = textField.text
}
```

However, if you're absolutely sure your alert has a text field, should see @Arun Gupta's answer.